# Check if a Person or Group column is empty in PowerShell

Tags: 2013, 2010, powershell

I have a Task owner column in SharePoint which is a Person or Group column. I am trying to check if this column is empty in Powershell

```
if($_["Task Owner"] -eq null)
```

This gives me the below error

```
you must provide a value expression following the '-eq' operator
```

Any help would be appreciated, TIA

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that PowerShell expects `null` value to be specified as `$null`,

In your case, this is the correct syntax:

```
if($_["Task Owner"] -eq $null)
```

Comment: yeah I just figured it out and added my own answer if someone misses this again :) Accepted the solution

Answer (score 0):

My bad, I missed the $ in front of the null

It worked once I changed null to $null

```
if($_["Task Owner"] -eq $null)
```